# Can't create wifi network

Tags: 10.04, wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share my WiFi Internet via WiFi?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72989/how-to-share-my-wifi-internet-via-wifi)

I have 2 laptops: first with wired connection and second is not.

When I try to create wireless network to share internet with second computer, looks like everything is fine (created network is available on first computer), but the second lapton doesn't see this network in it's available networks, but see some others (not mine), so the second computer can receive wifi.

Maybe I missed something.

Maybe I need some external device to my first laptop to seed data?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/72989/18612

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you need an external device. If you have a wired connection to the net then you should be able to share it wirelessly. I think if you want to share a wireless connection then you will need 2 wireless adapters, 1 to conect to the net, 1 to share the connection with your other computer. In Ubuntu 11.10 you can go to network click on the wireless tab then click on use as hotspot. If you have already done this then I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Peace