# WiFi hotspot during another WiFi connection

Tags: wireless-access-point, connection-sharing

I saw it in Windows 10. Notebook is connected to WiFi network via WPA2 Enterprise, let's call it "work network". I can't connect to this network from my smartphone but I can make WiFi hotspot in Windows and connect to it with smartphone. Windows is automatically share "work network" to hotspot WiFi and I can use this network to connecting to internet. Is it possible to achieve on Ubuntu?

Comment: Does Windows have (and so share) a wired connection to the Office network? - Here is what can be done with Ubuntu : Notebook connected to wired WorkNetwork and share it to a WiFi personal network hosted by the notebook

Comment: @cmak.fr that's not solution in that case.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72989/how-to-share-my-wifi-internet-via-wifi
this is not solution in my case. I dont want use hardware solutions.

Comment: I found working solution on second link https://askubuntu.com/a/1062026/62276